# Change background color of SearchView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the background color of my SearchView using both xml and code but none seems to be working.
XML:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">

   </SearchView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
@InjectView(R.id.searchView) private SearchView searchView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Why are these not working and how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add -
    searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

Did you connect the XML file to the activity?

For instance -

```
setContentView(R.layout.**YOURXMLHERE**);
```

Comment: I used RoboGuice to inject the activity layout.

Comment: Try searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);